# Risk of loss function Bernoulli random variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, loss-functions, estimators

[image]

Can anyone help me with the part b of the question? I understand the risk is expected value of the loss function, but how to incorporate expected value in the piece-wise function. I will be grateful.

I have first defined the loss function $(\theta - 0)^{2}$ when $\overline{X}< 0.5$ $\Rightarrow$ $\theta<0.5$ $\Rightarrow$ $R_{T1}=E[ (\theta - 0)^{2}]<(0.5)^{2}=0.25$

Similarly for second piece I have defined the loss function $(\theta - 1)^{2}$ when $\overline{X}> 0.5$ $\Rightarrow$ $1-\theta<0.5$ $\Rightarrow$ $R_{T1}=E[ (\theta - 1)^{2}]<(0.5)^{2}=0.25$

Similarly for the last part $R_{T1}=E[ (\theta - 1/2)^{2}]=0$.

So I concluded that $R_{T1}=E[ (\theta -T_{1} )^{2}]<0.25$

So, now can you verify the solution or point out mistakes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add the [tag:self-study] and edit to show us your thoughts so people know how bets to help you.

Comment: @mdewey done. Thanks!